# How to detect if a program has been compiled using -threaded?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, process, ghc

I'm working on a Haskell daemon that uses POSIX fork/exec together with file locking mechanism. My experiments show that file locks aren't inherited during `executeFile` with `-threaded` runtime (see also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-cafe/becykk5iaRQ)), no matter if I use `+RTS -N` or not. So I'd like to add a check to be sure that the daemon ins't compiled with `-threaded`. Is there a portable way to detect it?

Comment: `setNumCapabilities 2` and check that `getNumCapabilities` returns 1?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is the [`rtsSupportsBoundThreads` value](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent.html#v:rtsSupportsBoundThreads) value in `Control.Concurrent` for this. For example:

```
module Main (main) where

import Control.Concurrent

main :: IO ()
main = print rtsSupportsBoundThreads
```

And during test:

```
$ ghc -fforce-recomp Test.hs; ./Test
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking Test ...
False
$ ghc -fforce-recomp -threaded Test.hs; ./Test
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking Test ...
True
```

Here is its [C-part source code](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/d71bbe79e222ea286c2fd465abfde58280450c3a/rts/Threads.c#L461):

```
HsBool
rtsSupportsBoundThreads(void)
{
#if defined(THREADED_RTS)
  return HS_BOOL_TRUE;
#else
  return HS_BOOL_FALSE;
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a dirty hack and might be not portable but I can confirm it works for ghc-7.6.3 on linux:

```
isThreaded :: IO (Maybe Bool)
isThreaded = do
  tid  <- forkIO $ threadDelay 1000000
  yield
  stat <- threadStatus tid
  killThread tid
  case stat of
    ThreadBlocked BlockedOnMVar  -> return (Just True)
    ThreadBlocked BlockedOnOther -> return (Just False)
    _                            -> return Nothing
```

See [BlockedOnOther docstring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/GHC-Conc.html#t%3aBlockReason) for details.