# How to detect if setNumCapabilities will work

Tags: haskell, ghc

Given the following program, with GHC 7.6:

```
import Control.Concurrent
main = do
    setNumCapabilities 8
    putStrLn "After"
```

If I build with `ghc --make` and run I get:

```
main: setNumCapabilities: not supported in the non-threaded RTS
After
```

The warning about the non-threaded RTS comes because I didn't build with `-threaded`. I would like to modify this code so that it doesn't print anything even if it didn't work. For example, if I could detect that the RTS was non-threaded, then I could avoid the `setNumCapabilities`. I don't want to put something on the stdout of the calling program.

Comment: I'd be happy to agree this is indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [`rtsSupportsBoundThreads`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Control-Concurrent.html#v:rtsSupportsBoundThreads) before.

Also see: [How to detect if a program has been compiled using -threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839824/how-to-detect-if-a-program-has-been-compiled-using-threaded)